# Circles and lines geometry problem

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

[image]

Here is my task: An arbitrary ray $OE$ crosses the circle at point $D$:
$$x ^ 2 + (y - a / 2) ^ 2 = (a / 2) ^ 2$$
and a tangent to it(at point $E$), passing through point $C$, diametrically opposite to $O$.

Through points $D$ and $E$, straight lines are drawn parallel to the axes $Ox$ and $Oy$, respectively, up to the intersection at point M.

Equate the line formed by the $M$ points and draw it (Agnesi's curl).

**My attempt**

I think that this problem need using Polar coordinates. But I have no idea how to start. Maybe if we assume that $M$ has coordinates $(x,y)$ we can find this point(using polar coordinates like $x=r\sin(q)$ or something like that) but how to equate the line? And of course I have already drawn it. After an hour i have idea if we find point $M$ can we use $M$-coordinates to get parametric equation of a line? If yes, how to make first step? Ok, after a few time i found $x$ like a coordinate of a point $M$ (i use as a parameter angle between $OE$ and $OC$ (q) so $x=tgqa/cosq$) how can find $OB$?

Comment: Point $O=(0,0)$ lies on the circle: it isn't possible that ray $OE$ crosses the circle at two other points $D$ and $E$. If the curve you want to construct is the witch of Agnesi, then see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witch_of_Agnesi

Comment: Hm. Ok i should add a drawing .

Comment: @Intelligentipauca edited and now simple to understand

Comment: Neither E nor D and nor E appear in your attached figure.

Comment: @Piquito like i said points arent right placed there. I dont know how to draw it normal using something like wolfram. I can add my photo but im bad in drawing. This picture only shows idea how to draw it (just replacing a points).

Comment: I took your picture, erased some of the point names and replaced them with new names; is the figure correctly labeled now?

Comment: @DavidK Yes. Right. Thank you.

Comment: a seem to be the radius. In your equation you are not using the sign properly for the specific selection of the ray - lucky enough you have a square.

Comment: Write the equation of OD - your ray. The intersection E has x when y=a. This is the x of M. y is defined by your equation.

Comment: @Moti Maybe im stupid, because ok OE=a/cosq what now? I cant write equation for OD.

Comment: @Moti a is not radius its diameter

Comment: Some hints for writing the formulas: `\cos` for the cosine function, `\tan` for the tangent; the "\" character formats them as function names so you get $\cos q$ instead of $cosq$ (but you have to insert a space, for example `\cos q`, or MathJax will look for a symbol named `cosq` which doesn't exist). You can use `\theta` to write $\theta$. And if you write $\tan qa$ people will not know if you mean $(\tan q)a$ or $\tan(qa),$ so $a\tan q$ is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spoiler alert: this is not a hint, here is a solution using cartesian coordinates.

The calculation is based on similarity of triangles $OBD$ and $OCE$. First we consider the right side of the curve ($x \ge 0$) and then we note that the curve is symmetric. Our objective is to find $y_M$ as a function of $x_M$.

From the similarity of triangles $OBD$ and $OCE$ we have:
$$\frac{OB}{OC} = \frac{BD}{CE} $$
$$\frac{y_M}{a} = \frac{x_D}{x_M} $$
$$\therefore y_M = a \frac{x_D}{x_M} \qquad(1)$$
Now, to find $x_D$ we note that $D$ is on the given circle and that $y_D = y_M$ :
$${x_D}^2 + (y_M - \frac a2)^2 = (\frac a2)^2 $$
$$\therefore {x_D}^2 = y_M (a - y_M) \qquad(2)$$
By squaring equation (1) and using equation (2) we have:
$$y_M = a^2 \frac{a-y_M}{{x_M}^2} $$
which can be rewritten as
$$y_M = \frac{a^3}{a^2 + {x_M}^2} \qquad(3)$$
which is the equation of the loci of $M$ . Note that the curve of desired loci is symmetric, and equation (3) accounts for positive as well as negative values of $x$ .

Answer (score 0):

In conventional polar coordinates $(\rho, \theta)$ we measure the angle $\theta$ counterclockwise from the $x$ axis.
Of course you can instead use the angle $q$ measured clockwise from the $y$ axis, but then you must be careful not to simply copy any formulas that were developed for shapes in conventional polar coordinates.
You have already correctly rederived at least one such formula, which is
$x = r \cos\theta$ when converting conventional polar coordinates to Cartesian
but is $x = r \sin q$ in your coordinates.

There are well-known formulas for a circle tangent to the origin in polar coordinates. You can derive a formula for your circle by substituting expressions with $r$ and $q$ for $x$ and $y$ in
$$ x^2 + (y - a/2)^2 = (a / 2)^2, $$
or perhaps more easily by adding the segment $CD$ to the figure and examining
the right triangle $\triangle ODC$ with right angle at $D.$

You should eventually be able to figure out both the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of $M$ using the angle $q$ as a parameter. That would be one way to describe the curve.

However, the fact that you have the formula for the circle in Cartesian coordinates suggests that someone was thinking of doing the whole problem in Cartesian coordinates.
Using the $x$ coordinate of $M$ -- you might say the $x$ coordinate is $x_M$ --
you can write an equation of the line $OE$ in Cartesian coordinates.
Then the coordinates of $D$ are what you get when you solve for $x$ and $y$
simultaneously in $ x^2 + (y - a/2)^2 = (a / 2)^2 $
and in the equation of the line $OE.$
What you're looking for is an equation relating the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of $M$.

So those are two ways of describing the curve.
There may be other hints in the context of the question that would suggest which one will be more desirable.

Answer (score 0):

[Agnesi curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qv175.png)

**Parametric equation**

$\theta = angle(Ox, OD) \qquad OC = a$

triangle (OCE) : $CE = \dfrac{a}{\tan \theta} = x_{M}$

triangle (ODC) : $OD = OC\cos\Big( \dfrac{\pi}{2}-\theta \Big)= a\cos\Big( \dfrac{\pi}{2}-\theta \Big) = a\sin \theta$

triangle (OHD) : $HD = OD\cos\Big( \dfrac{\pi}{2}-\theta \Big)= OD\sin \theta  = a\sin^{2}\theta = y_{M}$

equation : $x = \dfrac{a}{\tan \theta} \qquad y = a\sin^{2}\theta \qquad \theta \in [0, \pi]$